# Implot heat map for number of occurences

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

[image]

]
Here you can see only blue dots. Can I have different shades of colours based on the number of occurences. Or is there any other plot or library? It is fine if there is completely a different plot for my purpose. I wanted the scatter plot between two variables, a regression line and the region with different number of data points, it would be nice to get different shades of colours. In other words if a region has more data points concentrated, it could have a dark red. And if any region has less points plotted,it could have very light red

```
df_new[['CRP0_VDDN','EYE_WIDTH']].head(50)
     CRP0_VDDN  EYE_WIDTH
0       1.200       54.6
1       1.200       66.3
2       1.200       58.5
3       1.200       58.5
4       1.200       62.4
5       1.200       54.6
6       1.200       66.3
7       1.200       66.3
8       1.200       66.3
9       1.200       62.4
10      1.200       54.6
11      1.200       66.3
12      1.200       62.4
13      1.200       50.7
14      1.200       62.4
15      1.200       66.3
16      1.200       58.5
17      1.200       66.3
18      1.200       54.6
19      1.200       50.7
20      1.200       58.5
21      1.200       66.3
22      1.200       58.5
23      1.200       54.6
24      1.200       54.6
25      1.200       66.3
26      1.200       54.6
27      1.200       62.4
28      1.200       58.5
29      1.200       46.8
30      1.200       54.6
31      1.200       66.3
32      1.175       70.2
33      1.175       66.3
34      1.175       62.4
35      1.175       66.3
36      1.175       50.7
37      1.175       54.6
38      1.175       66.3
39      1.175       66.3
40      1.175       54.6
41      1.175       54.6
42      1.175       54.6
43      1.175       58.5
44      1.175       58.5
45      1.175       50.7
46      1.175       62.4
47      1.175       74.1
48      1.126       58.5
49      1.126       62.4
```

Comment: You could try to make the dots semitransparent with e.g. `sns.lmplot(..., scatter_kws={'alpha': 0.5})`.

Comment: I tried, but that seems to be not my solution. It is fine if there is completely a different plot for my purpose. I wanted the scatter plot between two variables, a regression line and the region with different number of data points, it would be nice to get different shades of colours. In other words the intensity of data points should be known somehow

Comment: If you'd provide some toy data to reproduce a similar plot, people can experiment how different approaches would look like using different parameter settings. Maybe a [density plot](https://python-graph-gallery.com/1136-2/) could work?

Comment: Edit has been made, toy data has been added. I believe density plot doesn't fill my purpose of Regression line

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find something suitable here.

https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html

Or, here.

https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/seaborn-heatmaps-13-ways-to-customize-correlation-matrix-visualizations-f1c49c816f07

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tips_df = sns.load_dataset('tips')
tips_df.head()

sns.heatmap(tips_df.corr(), annot = True, vmin=-1, vmax=1, center= 0, cmap="YlOrBr")
```

[image]

```
sns.heatmap(tips_df.corr(), annot = True, vmin=-1, vmax=1, center= 0, cmap= 'coolwarm', linewidths=3, linecolor='black')
```

[image]